# comapre value in two dataframe for alerting

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have df like below with:-

```
import pandas as pd 
  
# initialize list of lists 
data = [[0, 2, 3],[0,2,2],[1,1,1]] 
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['10028', '1090','1058'])
```

[image]

The clauses are the column names are dynamic sometimes it's 3 columns and sometimes it's 5 columns sometimes 1 column.

and I have on other df which is telling me the anomaly

```
# initialize list of lists 
data = [[0,1,1]] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['10028', '1090','1058'])
```

[image]

Now if any of the columns in df2  is having value 1 it means it's an anomaly then I have to alert. the only clause is I want to check if 1090 is 1 in df2 then the value of 1090 in df1 and if it's less than 4 then do nothing

As of now, I am doing it like this:-

```
if df2.any(axis=1).any() == True:
    print("alert")
```

Comment: So, basically you want alert if any of the columns in df2 is having value 1 but with one exception right?

Comment: I want to alert if a column in df2 is having value 1 and if the same corresponding column in df1 is having a value higher than 5